# How can I check environment variables from my Ansible playbook?

Tags: linux, ansible, environment-variables

I'm trying to make an Ansible role to define environment variables on my remote server but my linter asks me to condition any use of the command module, using "when:" statements

```
- name: Set environment variables in .profile file
  become: true
  template:
    src: .profile.j2
    dest: "{{ env_home.value }}/.profile"
    owner: "{{ unix_user.name }}"
    group: "{{ unix_user.group }}"
    mode: 0777

- name: Load environment variables from .profile file
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ unix_user.name }}"
  command: "/bin/bash {{ env_home.value }}/.profile"
```

This code returns changed/ok, but I have no clue if the environment variables are actually well defined following the `export {{ env_home.variable }}={{ env_home.value }}` written in my .profile template, and I'd like to add a task checking if all environment variables are defined or not before loading the .profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All environment variables are stored in fact `ansible_env`. So you may run task `setup` after your code to gather new facts again and then check values of variables in `ansible_env`.

Comment: Isn't this gonna give me environment variables on my Ansible Controller rather than my server's variables ?

Comment: Nope, ```ansible_env``` variable is set only if you gather facts from the servers, and this variable is unique for each server.